# add intermitting ids in piped output

Tags: bash, scripting

I want to iterate through a list of document files, process them and output the result in a single file, but with the file ids indicated.
The processing involves: markup removal, tokenization, sentence splitting.

The input is something like this:

```
/path/to/file1 docid1 
/path/to/file2 docid2
```

The output would be the tokens, one per line, with markup containing docid and sentence nr:

```
<D=docid1.1>
tok1
tok2
</D>
<D=docid1.2>
...
</D>
<D=docid2.1>
...
</D>
```

The way I am doing it now is the following:

```
>$outfile
for filename_id in `cat $filelist`
do
 filename=`echo $path_id | cut -f1 -d' '`
 docid=`echo $path_id | cut -f2 -d' '`

 strip_markup.sh $filename \
 | tokenize.sh \
 | sentence_split.sh \
 | add_ids.sh $docid
 | >> $outfile
done
```

Now the problem is that I have fairly many small files, and each of the steps has some startup time (starting JVM, loading models etc.), some considerably so. The actual running time is very fast, as seen with very big (artificial) files.
It has come out by analysis that this step (tokenization and sentence splitting) is the most time-consuming one in my project (some other conceptually more 'complicated' stuff runs faster.)

Basically what I would like to do is giving the strip_markup.sh script the whole filelist instead of single filenames, but the ids need to be inserted afterwards somehow. The input and output format should rather not be changed if not absolutely necessary. 
Also we would like to use the modules we have for tokenization and splitting, because a lot of data is already processed that way.

Any ideas how to go about it?

Answer (score 1):

Can I assume that `add_ids.sh` simply prepends a `<D=$docid>` line and appends a `</D>` line to it input? Perhaps the following will work. Notice I use a `while` loop and `read` command to extract the filename and docid without the need for external processes.

```
< $filelist
while read filename docid; do
    echo "<D=$docid>"
    strip_markup.sh $filename |
    tokenize.sh |
    sentence_split.sh
    echo "</D>" 
done > $outfile
```

Since all the standard output in the loop body is serialized to the output file at once, there's no need for a separate process that takes the tokenized and split data as input in order to wrap it in a `<D` element. Altogether, this approaches removes several processes per iteration (the two subshells and the associated `cut`s for processing the input, as well as the process for `add_ids.sh`).

Comment: The add_ids.sh also prints the sentence number. Anyways, the principle problem still exists with you solution, I think.

Comment: In that case, how does `add_ids.sh` get the sentence number from `sentence_split.sh`? There appears to be global state being shared among your scripts that isn't visible in the code you've posted. I would suggest posting the contents of all your scripts, but I think this question is beyond the scope of stackoverflow and should perhaps be moved to codereview.stackexchange.com.